# Traverse an array from outer elements to inner ones

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

We are doing the following exercise: [Snail](https://www.codewars.com/kata/521c2db8ddc89b9b7a0000c1).

To be able to complete the program we have thought about the following example:

Given the array:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1]
[4, 5, 6, 4]
[7, 8, 9, 7]
[7, 8, 9, 7]


1. Iterate over first row (i==0) j++
[0,0]=1, [0,1]=2, [0,2]=3, [0,3]=1

2. Traverse last column (j==array[i].length-1) i++
[1,3]=4, [2,3]=7, [3,3]=7

3. Iterate over last row (i==array.length-1) j--
[3,2]=9, [3,1]=8, [3,0]=7

4. Go up into first column, do not take first row (j==0) (0>i<array.length-1) i--
[2,0]=7, [1,0]=4

5. Iterate over second row, do not take the last column (i==1) (-1>j<array.length-2) j++
[1,1]=5, [1,2]=6

6. Get middle elements
[2,2]=9, [2,1]=8
```

We have written the following code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Snail {
    public static int[] snail /**/ (int[][] array) {
      System.out.println("array: "+Arrays.deepToString(array));

      /*
      1. Iterate over first row (i==0) j++
      2. Traverse last column (j==array[i].length-1) i++
      3. Iterate over last row (i==array.length-1) j--
      4. Go up into first column, do not take first row (j==0) (0>i<array.length-1) i--
      5. Iterate over second row, do not take the last column (i==1) (-1>j<array.length-2) j++
      6. Do it and finally get the middle elements (i==2) (0<j<array[i].length-1)
      */

      List<Integer> firstRow = getRow(0,0,array[0].length,1,array);
      System.out.println("firstRow: "+Arrays.toString(firstRow.toArray()));

      List<Integer> lastColumn = getColumn(array[0].length-1,1,array[0].length,1,array);
      System.out.println("lastColumn: "+Arrays.toString(lastColumn.toArray()));

      List<Integer> lastRow = getRow(array.length-1,(array[array.length-1].length) - 2,-1,-1,array);
      System.out.println("lastRow: "+Arrays.toString(lastRow.toArray()));

      List<Integer> firstColumn = getColumn(0,array[0].length-2,0,-1,array);
      System.out.println("firstColumn: "+Arrays.toString(firstColumn.toArray()));

      List<Integer> middle = getRow(1,1,array[1].length-1,1,array);
      System.out.println("middle: "+Arrays.toString(middle.toArray()));


      List<Integer> middle2 = getRow(2,array[1].length-2,0,-1,array);
      System.out.println("middle2: "+Arrays.toString(middle2.toArray()));


      middle.addAll(middle2);
      firstColumn.addAll(middle);
      lastRow.addAll(firstColumn);
      lastColumn.addAll(lastRow);
      firstRow.addAll(lastColumn);
      System.out.println("firstRow: "+Arrays.toString(firstRow.toArray()));

      return firstRow.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
   }

   public static List<Integer> getRow(int row, int from, int to, int modifier, int[][] array){
     List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

     for(int j=from; Math.max(j,to)>Math.min(j,to); j+=modifier){
       System.out.println("j: "+j);
       result.add(array[row][j]);
     }
     return result;
   }

   public static List<Integer> getColumn(int column, int from, int to, int modifier, int[][] array){
     List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

     for(int j=from; Math.max(j,to)>Math.min(j,to); j+=modifier){
       System.out.println("j: "+j);
       result.add(array[j][column]);
     }
     return result;
   }

}
```

As you would notice, we have followed the steps. However, how could we make this solution for whatever array's size is being given?

Currently the posted code passes the first test, but not the second one (so we would need a way o answer this exercise for all possible array's sizes):

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;

public class SnailTest {

  @Test
    public void SnailTest0() {
        int[][] array
                = {{1, 2, 3, 1},
                {4, 5, 6, 4},
                {7, 8, 9, 7},
                {7, 8, 9, 7}};
        int[] r = {1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 7, 7, 9, 8, 7, 7, 4, 5, 6, 9, 8};
        test(array, r);
    }

  @Test
    public void SnailTest1() {
        int[][] array
                = {{1, 2, 3},
                {4, 5, 6},
                {7, 8, 9}};
        int[] r = {1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4, 5};
        test(array, r);
    }

 public String int2dToString(int[][] a) {
        return Arrays.stream(a).map(row -> Arrays.toString(row)).collect(joining("\n"));
    }

    public void test(int[][] array, int[] result) {
        String text = int2dToString(array) + " should be sorted to " + Arrays.toString(result);
        System.out.println(text);
        Assert.assertArrayEquals( result, Snail.snail(array));
    }

}
```

How could we improve this algorithm to traverse an array from outer elements to inner ones?, how would you modify this algorithm to be able to handle whatever array's size is being given?

Comment: You have the wrong expression for a column. Instead of 'array[i].length-1' you should use 'array[i][length-1]' This will get the results for row i, last column.

Answer (score 0):

You need a generic algorithm that can print what you want for any given array having dimensions `n, m`.

This is very similar to the spiral printing of a 2-D array problem you can find anywhere on the internet.

Here is a sample code:

```
// declare n, m as number of rows and number of columns
// of the given matrix "array"

int startCol = 0, endCol = m - 1;
int startRow = 0, endRow = n - 1;

while(startRow <= endRow && startCol <= endCol) {
    for(int i = startCol; i <= endCol; i++) {
        System.out.println(array[startRow][i]);
    }
    for(int j = startRow + 1; j <= endRow; j++) {
        System.out.println(array[j][endCol]);
    }
    for(int i = endCol - 1; i >= startCol; i -= 1) {
        System.out.println(array[endRow][i]);
    }
    for(int j = endRow-1; j > startRow; j--) {
        System.out.println(array[j][startCol]);
    }

    startCol++;
    endCol--;
    startRow++;
    endRow--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is rather tricky to write a correct algorithm that works for any array size. We can think of this as a recursive problem, we copy the outer "layers" of the array, and then end up with a smaller array. The smaller array has 2 less rows and 2 less columns. We continue repeating this process until the the nested array is not empty (has zero rows or zero columns). Here is my code with a couple of tests:

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals;

import org.junit.Test;

public class SnailTest {
  public static int[] snail(int[][] a) {
    return snail(a, 0, 0, new int[a.length * (a.length > 0 ? a[0].length : 0)], 0);
  }

  private static int[] snail(int[][] a, int row, int col, int[] result, int offset) {
    if (offset == result.length) {
      return result;
    }

    int height = a.length - 2 * row;
    int width = a[row].length - 2 * col;

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
      result[offset++] = a[row][col + i];
    }
    for (int j = 1; j < height - 1; j++) {
      result[offset++] = a[row + j][col + width - 1];
    }
    if (height > 1) {
      for (int i = width - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        result[offset++] = a[row + height - 1][col + i];
      }
    }
    if (width > 1) {
      for (int j = height - 2; j > 0; j--) {
        result[offset++] = a[row + j][col];
      }
    }
    return snail(a, row + 1, col + 1, result, offset);
  }

  @Test
  public void test3x3() {
    assertArrayEquals(snail(new int[][] { //
        { 1, 2, 3 }, //
        { 8, 9, 4 }, //
        { 7, 6, 5 } }), //
        new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 });
  }

  @Test
  public void test4x4() {
    assertArrayEquals(snail(new int[][] { //
        { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, //
        { 12, 13, 14, 5 }, //
        { 11, 16, 15, 6 }, //
        { 10, 9, 8, 7 } }), //
        new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 });
  }
}
```